# Does a neighborhood of a point include that point?

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through the topology problem set in baby Rudin and I'm wondering if a neighborhood $N_r(p)$ of a point $p$ in a metric space automatically contains $p$, or just $\forall q|d(p,q)<r$, but not necessarily $p$.

My intuition says that because $d(p,p)=0$ and $0<r$, $p$ should automatically be in any neighborhood of $p$, but I wanted to verify that I was correct.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Neighboorhod included the point.

Comment: Sometimes the term "punctured neighborhood/ball" is used for a neighborhood/ball minus the point in question.

Comment: Yes it does, see the [definition on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Neighbourhood_(mathematics)&oldid=698211406#Definition).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. From That definition we are are talking about all points within a radius $r$ of $p$.